# Object reference not set to an instance of an object Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script is attached to a coin that when picked does that issue.
There is nothing to attach in the inspector.

The `CoinMagnet state` is assigned to another object (as a magnet).

```
public void Start()
    {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        pu = Player.GetComponent<PowerUps>();       
    }

private void Update()
    {

        if (pu.CurrentPowerState == PowerUps.State.CoinMagnet) //issue here
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(Player.transform.position, transform.position) < CoinMagnetRadius)
           ...
           ...
        }
    }
```

Here is the Powerups class

```
public State CurrentPowerState;
 public enum State
    {
        None,
        Invincible,
        CoinMagnet,

    };
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging this?

Comment: Yes, and is shows no errors found.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an error if you're posting this on SO...

Comment: Right, using a breackpoint, says pu is null.

Comment: Then there's your problem.  That component doesn't exist on the player.

Comment: Right, i edited the script name and the player was deprived of the script. Thanks guys for ur time

Comment: debugging is not a show-errors type of thing.  It is an interactive process in which *you* are highly involved

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems that your player object does not have a PowerUps component.
Attach that script to the player object in your scene and it should work.

**Edit:**
A stack trace about the error or the concrete error message could help resolving the issue.